# PuTTY - Server Unexpectedly Closed Network Connection

Tags: security, ssh, shell, connection, putty

I have two servers that I have been able to connect fine as s1.website.com and s2.website.com

I connected to s1.website.com earlier today without any issues, however, when I connected to s2.website.com it gave me the "Server Unexpectedly Closed Network Connection"

I have researched this elsewhere and someone concluded it to a "brute force attempt" However, I know this is not the case.

If anyone else has had this issue please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Is this before or after you enter your credentials?

Comment: Output from the SSH logs on s2.website.com might be useful, too.

Answer (score -1):

@Scott: Before credentials are entered.
@RainyRat: Not sure what you mean, does every website have a s2 subdomain that shows SSH logs O_o?

Restarted SSH and everything was good.

Comment: `s2.website.com` is the machine you were SSHing into, right?

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, I guess "restarting" your service isn't exactly a fix... but it worked. @Bill, no I was not SSH'ing into s2.website.com, just website.com

Comment: Well, I took that from you saying 'I connected to s1.website.com earlier today without any issues, however, when I connected to s2.website.com it gave me the "Server Unexpectedly Closed Network Connection"'

The downvote is probably from the combination of a question without enough data to provide a useful answer, and the edit of "oh, I restarted and it went away"